# Rolling Deployment of Java application in Weblogic

Tags: deployment, weblogic12c

I am trying to understand if rolling deployment of application is possible in Weblogic. Weblogic version is 12.1.2.0.0.

"By rolling deployment I mean, deploying the new version to a single node or a child cluster, by removing the node or child cluster from targets of existing deployment. This is to make sure that the current version of deployment on existing cluster is still functioning, probably with degraded performance, due to removing a node/a child cluster.
The operation team can verify if the intended change has worked." Once verified then the target for the deployment can be updated to add rest of the child cluster(s).

I am aware of the -redeploy option available in Weblogic, which mean no outage, but it does the deployment to the same target as the original deployment.

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:8802
-username weblogic -password weblogic -name VersionedApp
-targets adminServer -redeploy -source
C:/tmp/VersionedApp2 -appversion version2
```

However not sure how will it behave, if there is an active DB in the backend.

Any insight on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer anyone will have for you other than "try it". What do you want to know that's not in the Oracle docs? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/redeploy.htm#DEPGD258 Are you seeing a specific problem? You can have two versions of the app at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at -adminmode atribute for deploying. In Oracle Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DEPGD/wldeployer.htm#DEPGD318

You need first enable admin port, and than application which is deployed in adminmode can be only accessed only by adminport (context is visible at admin port not at production one).
Once tests are ok, you can promote application from "admin" state to "active" one by using "-start" parameter in weblogic.Deployer.